# html correct link path to another directory within <a href> tag

Tags: html

Supppose you are here `http://domain.com/category/month/123`.
What's the correct way to put a link to `http://domain.com/category` on that page?
Is `<a href="/../category">...</a>` a proper way to do that? It works, but I'm not sure if this is correct and the best way.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of:

- `../`
- `/category`
- `//domain.com/category`
- `http://domain.com/category`

You shouldn't use `/../category` as the logic for that is "Start at the top, then go up a level, wait there is no level … ignore that bit then, then go to category".

Answer (score 1):

you can use "/category", the domain will be added automatically.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="../../category">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an absolute path as follows:

```
<a href="/category/">link</a>
```